# RegEx for matching limited element class attributes

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds

I need the divs contents where the divs classes are red or green:

```
$s = '<div class="red">111</div> xxx <div class="green">222</div>';

preg_match_all('!<div class="(red|green)">(.*?)</div>!', $s, $tomb);
```

This works fine, but I don't need the first backreference, only the second, the div content. I tried with assertion:

```
preg_match_all('!<div class="(?=red|green)">(.*?)</div>!', $s, $tomb);
```

but it does not match anything.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: Regex is not really suited for html. I advice you to use simplexml or domdocument to work with html.. you can use xpath for more easy selections